# bash - checking if a string contains #

Tags: bash, shell

I am trying to read a parameter file in a shell script and would want to skip the lines which start with "#". Have been trying it on Ubuntu VM (default bash) and for something that I can't understand, it doesn't seem to work.

Following is the pseudo-code that I am using:

```
while read line
do          
    if  [ grep -q "#" <<< "$line" ]; then
        ## Do nothing (Commented Out)           
        echo "$line Line is Commented out"          
    elif [ "$line" = "" ]; then     
        ## Do nothing (Blank Line)          
        echo "Blank line"                       
    else
        #echo "read line is $line"              
        ...some logic here
    fi
done <input_file.ini
```

This yields the the following error: `Syntax error: redirection unexpected`

The `if [[ $line == *#* ]]` construct doesn't seem to work. My earlier experience was on AIX where everything worked fine.

Could someone guide me what I am doing wrong here?

PS: On a related note, how do I handle cases where I don't want to do anything? e.g. when there is no '#' character in the read line, I don't want to do anything. I can't leave my if block blank so I am just using echo 'some random' text. My task works good but just wanted to understand what's a good practice to handle this.

Comment: The -v option is what you want to invert a search. `grep -v '^#'`

Comment: `[[ $line = *"#"* ]]` works fine, **if** your shell is really bash. If you have a `/bin/sh` shebang, or starting your shell with `sh yourscript`, it'd be trouble.

Comment: BTW, the conventional noop is `:`; it's a synonym for `true`, but one that implies that it's a placeholder. You can also pass it arguments and expect them to be ignored, as in `: "do nothing here"`

Comment: `[ grep ...` is broken because of the `[`; you're passing `grep` as an argument to `[`, which is a command itself.

Comment: echo $0 yields bash. Besides, I have the shebang as the first line of the script. Suggests me that the shell is bash. Am I missing anything?

Comment: Are you actually using `[[ $line = *"#"* ]]`, **exactly** as I gave it there? Note the quoting.

Comment: See https://ideone.com/jEI6iP, showing the code I described working. Can you generate a similarly self-contained example showing it broken?

Comment: Yes Charles. 
[code]
while read line
do   
 if  [[ $line = *"#"* ]]; then
  ## Do nothing (Commented Out)   
  echo "$line Line is Commented out"   
 elif [ "$line" = "" ]; then  
  ## Do nothing (Blank Line)   
  echo "Blank line"      
 else
  #echo "read line is $line"    
  KEY="$(echo $line | cut -d '=' -f1)"
  VALUE="$(echo $line | cut -d '=' -f2)"
  eval `echo $KEY`=`echo $VALUE`
  echo "$KEY\t\t-\t\t$VALUE"
 fi 
done < ${SCHEDULER_LOC}/inputs/script_params.ini [/code]

Comment: Not in a comment, please. [edit] into the question or create your own example at http://ideone.com/ or a similar online REPL.

Comment: Note, though, the words **self-contained**. If something only works if I create a `script_params.ini` file first, it isn't self-contained: People who don't have that file can't test it. See also the [mcve] definition.

Comment: Try `if [[ $line ~= '#' ]]`

Comment: Let me do that. Appreciate you trying to help.

Comment: @Bohemian, ...that should work *exactly* as well as `[[ $line = *'#'* ]]` -- which is to say that it's a perfectly good approach, but if we didn't have larger issues, the OP would presumably not be here.

Comment: Actually, the "Syntax error: redirection unexpected" gives us a very strong hint that our shell *isn't actually* bash (or is bash in POSIX compatibility mode), as `<<<` is a non-POSIX extension.

Comment: @SushantVasishta, ...if you `echo "$BASH_VERSION"` from inside the script, what do you get? Similarly, what's the output from `set -o | grep posix`?

Comment: https://ideone.com/6wqUmk (a quick mockup of what I am trying to do. The input file has been replaced by a dummy string). Still don't get the desired output - the line with # should take me to the first if block.

Comment: echo $BASH_VERSION
4.3.48(1)-release

Comment: That's blank because the assignment doesn't work. `line = "#test=temp"` isn't valid syntax -- you need to take out the spaces around the `=`

Comment: See the version at https://ideone.com/RJujvg, which properly returns *Line is Commented out*.

Comment: BTW, using `eval` that way is prone to security vulnerabilities. `printf -v "$KEY" %s "$VALUE"` is a slightly safer way to do indirect assignments. *Much* safer would be to prefix the keys (so your input file can't change `PATH` or `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` or other security-sensitive variables) or load into an associative array (so the real environment isn't modified). See [BashFAQ #48](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/048) for discussion of why `eval` is considered risky.

Comment: The `if/elif/else` chain really points to a common approach: `while read line; do case $line in \#*|"") continue;; *) process line;; esac; done < input`

Comment: I am honestly unsure of why it's not happening. I am still getting the error I was encountering earlier.

Here is the picture of all I am trying to do. It's a simple thing apparently and it all worked fine earlier. 

https://ibb.co/mieCpT

The code is visible and so is the execution output. The small white bottom right corner is what I am trying to read in.

Comment: And thanks for the inputs on eval. I'd want to implement that, once this challenge is sorted.

I've limited understanding of shell scripting and these inputs definitely help me a lot. Much appreciated.

Comment: `[[: not found` very unambiguously means your script is being run with a shell other than bash.

Comment: If, as you say, you just want to look at the first character in `$line`, and you are using `bash`, you can get it with `${line:0:1}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is clearly running with `/bin/sh`, not bash.

An alternative to `[[ $line = *"#"* ]]` that works with `/bin/sh` is `case`.

Thus, the following will work with `/bin/sh`, or when invoked with `sh yourscript`:

```
#!/bin/sh
while read -r line; do : line="$line"
  case $line in
    *"#"*) echo "Line is commented out: $line";;
    "")    echo "Line is empty" ;;
    *)     key=${line%%=*}
           value=${line#*=}
           eval "$key="'$line'  # unsafe, but works with /bin/sh, which doesn't have better
                                # indirect assignment approaches.
           printf '%s\t\t-\t\t%s\n' "$key" "$value"
           ;;
  esac
done <input_file.ini
```

---

Alternately, consider putting in a guard to handle the case when your script is invoked with a non-bash shell:

```
#!/bin/bash
case $BASH_VERSION in
  '')
    echo "ERROR: Run with a non-bash shell" >&2
    if [ "$tried_reexec" ]; then
      echo "ERROR: Already attempted reexec and failed" >&2
      exit 1
    fi
    if [ -s "$0" ]; then
      export tried_reexec=1
      exec bash "$0" "$@"
    fi
  ;;
esac

while read -r line; do
  if [[ $line = *"#"* ]]; then
    echo "Line is Commented out: $line"          
  elif [[ "$line" = "" ]]; then
    echo "Blank line"                       
  else
    key=${line%%=*}; value=${line#*=}
    printf -v "$key" %s "$value"
    printf '%s\t\t-\t\t%s\n' "$key" "$value"
  fi
done <input_file.ini
```

Comment: The # line still getting processed in the third block, when I used the first code snippet. The alternate code works good.

Makes me wonder why echo $0 shows me bash, if my shell isn't truly bash.

Comment: `echo $0` run **where**? In your interactive shell, or in the script? The interactive shell you start the script from is a *completely different shell* than the instance that's actually invoked to run the script. (That's why running `cd` in a script doesn't change the current directory of your interactive shell, for example).

Comment: Re: the first snippet not working, though -- please run `sh -x scriptname`, and paste the log somewhere I can access it. (Being ad-free, https://gist.github.com/ is ideal).

Comment: @SushantVasishta, ...also be sure you're testing against the current version -- the initial one was missing quotes.

Answer (score 0):

I really wasn't able to figure out the exact problem with double [[ ]] and the character search in a string. Thanks to everyone who tried to help me out. However this was acting as a deterrent and I didn't want to continue to fiddle for too long, I used a slightly different approach to handle my situation.

The following code works for me now:

```
while read line
do      
    first_char=`echo $line | cut -c 1`

    if  [ "$first_char" = "#" ]; then           
        : "do nothing here. Line is commented out"
    elif [ "$line" = "" ]; then     
        : "do nothing here. Blank line"                 
    else                
        KEY="$(echo $line | cut -d '=' -f1)"
        VALUE="$(echo $line | cut -d '=' -f2)"
        printf \v "$KEY" %s "$VALUE"

        echo "$KEY\t\t-\t\t$VALUE"
    fi
done < ${SCHEDULER_LOC}/inputs/script_params.ini
```

Also I was able to learn few things so incorporated them as well. I did get few negative scores for this question. Understandably so since this might be rudimentary for the experts but it was a genuine problem I was seeking some guidance on. Still, I am thankful that I learnt something new. Kudos to the community.

Comment: `first_char=$(echo $line | cut -c 1)` is both buggy and **really** slow. If your line is `* foo *`, then `echo $line` will instead be a list of files in your current directory. (Re: "really slow", this is because command substitutions `fork()` off a whole new copy of your shell; so do pipelines; and `cut` requires not just a `fork()` but also an `exec`, compared to using bash-builtin string manipulation which all happens in-process).

Comment: Also, `printf -v` is `-v`, not `\v`... though it won't work with `/bin/sh`, being a bashism itself.

Comment: I am unsure if followed your comment about the echo $line, @Charles Duffy. My understanding is, I am reading the input file, line by line and every time I read the first character of the line to check my first loop condition. (The part about being slow is understandable but since this is gonna be one time a day activity and I won't even read more than 20 lines, I can manage that sluggishness)

Comment: I used printf -v, based on your recommendation and I got this illegal option error. Then I looked into the man page and used \v.

Comment: The recommendation was correct for bash, but your shell is not bash so it does not have `printf -v`. (If it were bash, `[[` would also work). `printf \v` is simply wrong -- it doesn't run an assignment.

Comment: I added an answer that shows a header you can put at the top of your file to switch to bash if the script is initially started with a non-bash shell. (For example, `#!/bin/bash` can be ignored if `sh somescript` is used instead of `bash somescript` or `./somescript`).